# How is it that the same find command can give two different results?

Tags: find, search, file-search

This has happened to me twice (EDIT: many times and I can replicate it) now.  I'm working on a Raspberry Pi, looking for a file I already know exists and so I type this command:

```
sudo find / -iname 'firefox_binary.py'
```

The first time I type it, it runs without errors, but it doesn't find the file. However, when I run the same command only seconds later, it finds it.

It's the same command, run in the same terminal window, under the same path, on the same system, with the same file structure, with only a few seconds separating the first run from the second run. How is this result even possible?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour? If so, how?

Comment: That doesn't sound right - execute it under strace?

Comment: I know it doesn't sound right, I acknowledge this in my question.  There's no need to downvote me, at least give me a chance to give you the evidence.  Here's a video I just made and uploaded: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDB_50RwWa8

Comment: What a nice mystery... Did you notice that the second search needs much longer to complete? What does `mount` say both times (just add it to the line with a semicolon)?

Comment: Here's the strace results from the first and second search respectively: http://lenschulwitz.com/find1.txt http://lenschulwitz.com/find2.txt  `mount` result on the way...

Comment: Yes, it is, and I did notice the difference in time.  Didn't think this sort of thing happened on linux, but I'm not experienced enough to know - apparently nobody else has noticed this either, but it's there.  Here's the commands (runs 1 and 2 respectively) with "; mount" added http://lenschulwitz.com/mount1.txt http://lenschulwitz.com/mount2.txt

Comment: OK; these are identical, so it isn't a delayed FS mount, and `/usr/local/` seems to be part of the RootFS on the internal flash. The differences in your straces start when entering a dir named `options`, after having left `sys_exit`. Next step: Can you find where these dirs are located?

Comment: sys_exit is here: `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/raw_syscalls/sys_exit`, there are two directories called options: `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options`, and `/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/ws/node_modules/options`.

Comment: Just a quick, lucky guess, or call it a working hypothesis: The `options` dir in question is the first one; the kernel debugging interface isn't fully established at the time you launch the first `find`, and it terminates right there for some reason. However, I've got no clue what to do against it, perhaps except waiting for another minute...

Comment: @Murphy I appreciate the hypothesis, however even after booting the pi and letting it sit there for 11 minutes, the first find command returns nothing, so it appears as though the first attempt at find allows the second to be successful.

Comment: Looking at the trace, `find` stops when it should be moving on from `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events` to `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options`. The trace doesn't tell us why. What distribution are you running? What version? What exact kernel version and build (`uname -a`, more details on configuration if this isn't the distribution-provided kernel binary)? What version of `find`?

Comment: `find -x` is useful for restricting it to the same filesystem and avoiding looking in the sys, proc, dev, and so on directories.

Comment: The upstream bug report (in case people want to follow it) is at https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47261

Comment: There are some questions for you on the upstream bug report!

Comment: Turns out this is a legitimate bug present in version 4.4.2, but it has been fixed in version 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a real bug found in find version 4.4.2, but the bug has been fixed in find version 4.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Given the findings above, as workaroud you could try to either restrict the search to `/usr`

```
sudo find /usr -iname 'firefox_binary.py'
```

or skip `/sys` in one of the following ways, whatever suits your use case best:

```
sudo find / -mount -iname 'firefox_binary.py'

sudo find / -not -path '/sys/*' -iname 'firefox_binary.py'
```

Another, but IMHO more ugly workaround would be to try triggering the population of the problematic dir(s) before searching, e. g. with

```
ls /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options
```

or

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/<some_file>
```

or whatever it takes.

I also suggest you file a bug report with the maintainers of your `find` (probably either *busybox* or [*findutils*](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=findutils)). I think `find` shouldn't just exit the recursion in this case, and at least it mustn't without an error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  It's not a major problem, as I can just type the command twice, but it's so unusual to see a built-in linux command just completely fail like this without any errors, that I thought I should report it here.  I've filed a bug report, thanks for the link.